# Zeppelin: how to download or save the Zeppelin notebook?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, emr, amazon-emr, apache-zeppelin

I am using Zeppelin sandbox with aws EMR.

Is there a way to download or save the zeppelin notebook in a way so that it can be imported into another Zeppelin server ?

Comment: This feature was added version 0.5.6 as show in the release note - https://zeppelin.incubator.apache.org/releases/zeppelin-release-0.5.6-incubating.html. You could download that version. I don't know if there any workarounds for earlier versions.

Comment: @DemetriKots  thanks for the info. pity, on EMR now only version 0.5.5 available

Comment: @DemetriKots - Why don't you add your comment as answer. It will be useful for others.

Comment: @Hellolad - For 0.5.5 you can take a backup of contents in incubator-zeppelin/notebook folder and copy it to required Zeppelin instances.

Comment: @SamuelAlexander Good point. I added the comment as an answer below and incorporated your additional advice about backing up the notebook directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in the comments above, this feature is available starting in version 0.5.6.  You can find more details in the [release notes](http://zeppelin.incubator.apache.org/releases/). Downloading and installing this version would solve that issue.

Given that you are using EMR, it looks like you will have to work with the version available.  As Samuel mentioned above, you can backup the contents of the incubator-zeppelin/notebook folder and make the transfer.